# In a bit of a CSS Pickle

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of making a CSS drop down menu and CSS has just thrown me a curve ball.

### Problem:

*When I hover over my "Tools" section, the `submenu` is a few pixels off my main menu*.

### Problem CSS:

```
#menubar ul li {
    font:bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 35px;
    /*Change this to 15px 35px;and it will work*/
    background:#666;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s;
    transition:all 0.2s;
}
```

I have broken it for the purpose of this question (And because I do not want to use `15px` padding, I want to use `10px`)

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/65ZAv/) so you can see exactly what I am talking about if I did not explain this correctly.

I have tried `Margin`, `Top` with negative values, all sorts of other things and cannot get this to stay glued to the main menu.

Please guide me in fixing this...

**EDIT**
Thank you ALL... This has been solved! :) +1 for all.

Comment: I would position the submenu ul absolutely so it always sites under the relative parent li. #menubar ul li ul { position:absolute; top:38px;} seems to do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5Yq5/)

In this CSS rule, you have this:

```
#menubar ul li ul {
    top:48px;
}
```

However, you should have this:

```
#menubar ul li ul {
    top:38px;
}
```

That should fix it with the existing code you have and not create any new code.

Alternatively, set it to `100%` instead, as it will take the `%` of the `ul` above it, pushing it always the correct height if you change the `ul`'s design in future.

Comment: Thanks man :) I like this solution.. No more code is always good! Ill accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

add  `top:-10px;` to `#menubar ul li`

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/65ZAv/1/)

Comment: SERIOUSLY!!! I tried `top` with negative values.. Maybe I added it in the wrong place. Is this the best / only way to accomplish it?

Comment: Haha, it happens to us all! im sure there are many little tricks to get what you want but it was the first I could think of

Comment: +1 for that, thanks bro - But I think Ill go with the other guy and not add anymore code :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in following code

```
#menubar ul li ul {
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:48px;    //Change this value and it will glued to upper menu
```

......

Answer (score 1):

Just set `top` to `100%` then it doesn't matter how big the parent is and will cope if the user resizes the text:

```
#menubar ul li ul {
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65ZAv/6/

Answer (score 1):

In to CSS class `#menubar ul li ul` you define `top:48px;`.

```
#menubar ul li ul {
    top:48px;
}
```

try to set `top:38px;`.

```
#menubar ul li ul {
    top:38px;
}
```